# Creating an extension does not include all the files when I test it

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

I am  trying to create a template so that am not repeating creating boiler plate code. But when I pack my nuget package its not including all the files.

For Example My Cs Project is

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup>
    <PackageType>Template</PackageType>
    <PackageVersion>1.0</PackageVersion>
    <PackageId>WebAPITemplate.API</PackageId>
    <Title>WebAPITemplate.API</Title>
    <Authors>Me</Authors>
    <Description>Templates to use when creating an application for Adatum Corporation. 
    </Description>
    <PackageTags>dotnet-new;templates;contoso</PackageTags>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <IsPackable>true</IsPackable>

    <IncludeContentInPack>true</IncludeContentInPack>
    <IncludeBuildOutput>false</IncludeBuildOutput>
    <ContentTargetFolders>content</ContentTargetFolders>
    <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);NU5128</NoWarn>
    <NoDefaultExcludes>true</NoDefaultExcludes>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi" Version="7.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.4.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\WebAPITemplate.Models\WebAPITemplate.Models.csproj" />
   </ItemGroup>

 </Project>
```

You will see here is my template.json

Here is my project layout

[image]

And here is my json template.json file which lives in .template.config
What I would expect to happen with the below config is that all the files that are in the solution be shown in the template but when i check out with nuget package manger all that are there are the two dlls that the program produces.

```
{
"$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/template",
"author": "DavidBuckley",
"classifications": [ "Web/WebAPI" ],
"name": "Custon API With auth",
"identity": "WebApiTemplate.API.CSharp",
"groupIdentity": "WebApiTemplate.API",
"shortName": "WebApiTemplate",
 
"tags": {
  "language": "C#",
  "type": "project"
},
"sourceName": "WebAPITemplate.API",
"preferNameDirectory": true,
"symbols": {
  "copyrightName": {
    "type": "parameter",
    "defaultValue": "David Buckley",
    "replaces": "Contoso"
  },
  "title": {
    "type": "parameter",
    "defaultValue": "Hello World from dotnet new",
    "replaces": "Hello World"
  },
  "symbols": {
    "Empty": {
      "type": "parameter",
      "datatype": "bool",
      "defaultValue": "false",
      "displayName": "Allow Test",
      "description": "Creates empty .editorconfig instead of the defaults for .NET."
    }
  },
  "primaryOutputs": [
    {
      "path": "\\WebAPITemplate.API\\WebAPITemplate.API.csproj"
    },
    {
      "path": "\\WebAPITemplate.Models\\WebAPITemplate.Models.csproj"
    }

  ],
  "exclude": [ "**/[Bb]in/**", "**/[Oo]bj/**", ".template.config/**/*", "**/*.lock.json" ]
}
}
```